# Distorted firefox upon start up

Tags: 20.04, firefox

I encounter a problem upon start up. Firefox starts directly after boot but it is distorted and shows a fine glitching movement (see screenshot). It is unresponsive and persists till I close the window and restart firefox after which it appears just normal.
[image]

I did online search but found nothing relevant. I did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` but it didn't help. Then I uninstalled and reinstalled firefox to no avail.

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on ASUS ZenBook UX363EA. There was no any problem with Firefox before this started to appear.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can disable firefox starting on boot by going into Startup Applications, finding firefox and removing it (if it's there, otherwise we need more steps to find why it's opening incorrectly on startup)

Comment: @Esther thank you, it was added there intentionally, the question is why does it start distorted and unresponsive.

Comment: how do you usually start firefox? using the icon? can you check the .desktop for it to see if it is passing some other parameters when it starts?

Comment: @Esther using icon indeed. Do you mean /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop? Not sure, but I don't see something odd.

Comment: I mean what is the `Exec` string in the .desktop, and is it the same as in Startup Applications? If it's not just `firefox` for both, that could be part of the issue

Comment: @Esther Thanks for clarification. Both `Exec` and Startup Applications are the same (`/usr/bin/firefox`).

Comment: @Esther, sorry for repeated comments, it shows `Exec=firefox %u` in the above file, and also `Exec=firefox -new-window` and `Exec=firefox -private-window`

Comment: can you check off "open in terminal" and report on the output produced in the terminal?

Comment: @Esther in the above mentioned .desktop file, the only occurrence of terminal is: `Terminal=false`

Comment: I meant in Startup Applications, if there is an option to open in terminal, that would enable you to see output when it glitches. But do try @vanadium's solution, that is likely to help you. If it doesn't work switch the 2 for some larger number.

Comment: @Esther, I did check that indeed but didn't find this option. Thank you very much for your responses any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a line

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=2
```

to have some delay (2 seconds in this example, experiment for yourself how long you need) before starting Firefox. This will ensure the desktop will be fully ready once Firefox is started.

Comment: thank you very much, it works with 2 sec, 1 sec is still too short. This is, however, the answer to "how" to solve it, the only question remains is "why" this has started to appear recently.